# How to split android screen horizontal 2 vertical 3 total 6

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imagebutton

Ok i am trying to split screen size to horizontally equally and vertically 3 each part

Android studio on windows 8.1 api 9

Here image how i want

[image]

each image is exactly those sizes and i want them to proportionally scaled according to the lower resolutions

here my code that i tried and failed

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".Pokemon"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
  >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_monstermmorpg_1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_monstermmorpg_button_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"


            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_monstermmorpg_2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Register_monstermmorpg_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_monstermmorpg"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Login_monstermmorpg_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_pokemonets_1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_pokemonpets_button_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_pokemonets_2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Register_pokemonpets_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_pokemonpets"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Login_pokemonpets_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simply you can use a GridView

in the layout aspect

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".Pokemon"
    android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
  >

<LinearLayout


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightsum="2"
  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation:vertical
android:weightsum="3"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/register_monstermmorpg_1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_monstermmorpg_button_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"


            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/register_monstermmorpg_2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Register_monstermmorpg_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/login_monstermmorpg"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Login_monstermmorpg_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation:vertical
android:weightsum="3"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/register_pokemonets_1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_pokemonpets_button_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/register_pokemonets_2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Register_pokemonpets_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/login_pokemonpets"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Login_pokemonpets_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />
    </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_monstermmorpg_1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_monstermmorpg_button_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"


            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_monstermmorpg_2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Register_monstermmorpg_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_monstermmorpg"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Login_monstermmorpg_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_pokemonets_1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_pokemonpets_button_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/register_pokemonets_2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Register_pokemonpets_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_pokemonpets"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/Login_pokemonpets_land"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use one `LinearLayout` as parent with a `weightSum` of 4 and `orientation` vertical. Then use 3 `LinearLayout` childs with a `weightSum` of 2, `orientation` horizontal and a `weight` of 2 for the first one and 1 for the second and third one. Inside these `LinearLayout` put 2 `ImageButton` with `weight` of 1.

If you want an example tell me but i think that i was clear.

P.s. all the `layout_width` and `layout_height` have to be `match_parent`

Answer (score 1):

First you need a horizontal LinearLayout with a weight sum of 2.
Inside it, should be 2 vertical LinearLayouts with weight sums of 4, and weights of 1 each.
Inside those two layouts, add your 3 image buttons. Top has a weight of 2, others have a weight of 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Using layout weight can be a good solution.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button2" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button3" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button05"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```